# Get a GstBuffer/GstMemory/GstSample from an element in running pipeline

Tags: c, gstreamer

I need to randomly access image data in a running pipeline. Something like `gst_base_sink_get_last_sample()` but not for a sink element placed at the end of the pipeline. I need to inspect passing data in the middle of the pipeline while running, for example inspect the input buffer to the glupload. I also can not add `tee` to the pipeline to make a fork and send that to fakesink as `tee` has overheads of data copy for each frame. Is there any method I can use to extract current buffer/memory/sample of data in a `PLAYING` element in gstreamer pipeline?

Pipeline:
[image]

Comment: I think you might be able to use a pad probe for that. Have a look at the types of probes you can specify: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstpad.html?gi-language=c#GstPadProbeType. It seems that a `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER` might be what you need.

Comment: "as tee has overheads of data copy for each frame". That is a false assumption.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch, as I have seen examples and based on my experience, to use tee, I have to prepend queue to each branch and that will memcpy image data to be used in each branch. If you think that I'm wrong about it, then correct me as I'm facing speed bottleneck  somewhere else because of using tee and queue to fork my pipeline and it is copying every frame to be sent to each branch. Here's the actual [question]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74948375/branch-in-gstreamer-pipeline-but-without-data-copy)

Comment: Thanks @ChristianFritz, I guess it'll work. I'm going to give it a try and report the results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @FlorianZwoch, I made it using pad probe.
Every time I need to get access to data to probe it, I add a probe to any pad I want like this:

```
GstPad* pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(v4l2convert, "src");
gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, probe_callback, NULL, NULL);
gst_object_unref(pad);
```

and then in the callback function I can access data using these lines of code:

```
GstPadProbeReturn Gstreamer::probe_callback(
    GstPad* pad, GstPadProbeInfo* info, gpointer user_data)
{
    Q_UNUSED(user_data);
    gst_println("callback called");

    GstBuffer* buffer = gst_pad_probe_info_get_buffer(info);  // No need to unref later [see docs]
    GstCaps*   caps   = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);

    if (!buffer || !caps)
    {
        g_printerr("Probe callback failed to fetch valid data.");
        goto label_return;
    }

    // Consume data here

    return GST_PAD_PROBE_REMOVE;
}
```